# Android camera application restriction to 12 mp

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-camera, high-resolution

I am building a camera application in which i want a functionality that if the mobile camera is of 50 megapixels or any size It should only capture image in 12 megapixels size and its pixels should be restricted and resolution should be high.and image should have clear pixels ..

I have used camera2 dependency for restrictions but it doesn't work